# Batch file help 2 commands for adb at once

Tags: batch-file, command, adb

Im tryin to set 2 commands for a folder of apks im trying to push to /system/app/

so what im trying to do is push all apks in a folder to /system/app/ then set a chmod 644 command for those files being pushed

what i have is this to push the apks

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b SystemAPKs\*.apk') do stuff\adb.exe push SystemAPKs\%%a  /system/app/
```

what would be the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform multiple operations in the for loop.  Something like this:

```
for /f %%A IN ('dir /b SystemAPKs\*.apk') do (
    stuff\adb.exe push "%%~fA" /system/app/
    stuff\adb.exe shell chmod 644 "/system/app/%%~nxA"
)
```

---

Update, lets change the working directory of the script.  This will allow us to invoke adb with just the file name instead of the entire file path.

- Root

  - Script.bat
  - SystemAPKs

    - apk files to push
  - stuff

    - adb.exe
  - MarketAPKs
  - Nexus 4 drivers

Directory Structure

```
:: Make SystemAPKs the Working Directory
pushd SystemAPKs
for /f %%A IN ('dir /b *.apk') do (
    ..\stuff\adb.exe push "%%~nxA" /system/app/
    ..\stuff\adb.exe shell chmod 644 "/system/app/%%~nxA"
)
popd
```

Comment: above code works if apks are placed in root of the batch folder but its ignoring my SystemAPKs folder, so im getting files and dir not found unless placed in root, any way to change this to point to the SystemAPKs folder

Comment: Could you illustrate how your folder structure is set up? For Example this is how I am imagining the structure:
`Root` folder contains `Batch.bat`, `SystemAPKs` folder, and `stuff` folder.  `SystemAPKs` folder contains apks to push.  `stuff` folder contains `adb.exe`.

Comment: exactly that is the structure, I also have a MarketAPKS folder and a Nexus 4 Drivers folder all in root forgot to mention that so root folder has batch.bat, SystemAPKS folder,stuff folder, MarketAPKs folder,Nexus 4 drivers folder,

Comment: David, thank you so much that worked!!...  thank you for taking the time to help me!!!

Comment: It is my pleasure. Thank you for responding and marking the answer.  If you need any more help feel free to ask.  Also, I would encourage you to stick around on SO and help grow the community.

Comment: Least I could do, again thank you!!, I'm new to this (as u can tell lol) and when I found this site, I was so happy to find a community that helps each other in the way it does! I have alot to learn but this is the perfect place. Thanks again David!